# Delete from table A where not in (two other tables)

Tags: mysql

I need to delete cities that are not being used in table properties and owners.

I found this code:

```
DELETE from Table_A 
WHERE  id -- ID of Table_A
       not in (select ID FROM Table_B)
```

How it would look with a C table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `union` to join the results from table_B and table_C. Here is the documentation - http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-union-mysql.aspx. I have no mysql handy, but the following should work:

```
DELETE FROM Table_A WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT id FROM Table_B UNION DISTINCT SELECT id FROM Table_C
)
```

Comment: Something like: DELETE from Table_A 
WHERE  id
       not in (
SELECT id from Table_B 
UNION [DISTINCT | ALL]
SELECT id from Table_C 
        )
?

Comment: `[DISTINCT | ALL]` means you can add `DISTINCT`, `ALL` or none of them.

Comment: So i'll remove it @Doncho Gunchev

Comment: Didin't worked: SELECT id from A WHERE id not in ( SELECT city_id from B  UNION SELECT city_id FROM C UNION SELECT city_id FROM D ) . Thank's for the efford.